# Const rvalue compiler difference

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>


void f(int&& i)
{
    std::cout << "f(int&&)\n";
}

void f(const int&& i)
{
    std::cout << "f(const int&&)\n";
}


int fun_i()
{
    return 0;
}

const int fun_ci()
{
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    f(fun_i());
    f(fun_ci());
}
```

If I compile this with MSVC 2012, the output is:

```
f(int&&)
f(const int&&)
```

If I compile with GCC 4.7, the output is:

```
f(int&&)
f(int&&)
```

Which is correct?

(If I remove the second definition of f, the program will not compile under MSVC 2012, but it does compile under GCC 4.7.)

Comment: Note: There's almost no point in taking a `const&&` as a parameter.

Comment: But in the book C++ Primer Plus(by Stephen Prata) in Appendix F(The string Template Class), one of the constructors of basic_string is basic_string(basic_string&& str) noexcept; !! Why is it included anyway?

Comment: The `basic_string(basic_string&& str)` constructor is a so-called *move constructor*, something introduced in C++11. It may be marginally faster than the old *copy constructor*, `basic_string(const basic_string& str)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GCC is correct. From paragraph 4 of 3.10 Lvalues and rvalues [basic.lval]:

> Class prvalues can have cv-qualiﬁed types; non-class prvalues always have cv-unqualiﬁed types. [...]

A function call such as `fun_ci()` is in fact a prvalue*, and as such has type `int`, not `const int`. `int&&` is a better match than `const int&&`, and should be picked by overload resolution.

*: it's customarily said that top-level cv-qualifiers are ignored for non-class return types.

Comment: Thank you, Luc! I verified what you wrote by replacing 'int' with a class in the code, and then both compilers provide the same output: First without 'const', then with 'const'.

Comment: @ClausTøndering You could also try with an xvalue, e.g. you pass in `std::move(i)` for a non-`const` variable and a `const` variable.

Answer (score 2):

I'm inclined to say that gcc appears to be doing the right thing, based on a warning it emits:

```
stieber@gatekeeper:~$ g++ -std=c++11 -Wignored-qualifiers Test.cpp
Test.cpp:20:18: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
```